# How to convert dataframe to matrix based on 2 factor & 1 numeric columns

Tags: r, matrix

I have following dataframe:

```
structure(list(vnum1 = c(-1.38, 1.22, -0.17, -0.47, -0.08, -1.11, 
-1.56, -0.14, 0.55, -0.43, 0.25, 0.8, 0.77, -0.1, -0.21, -0.62, 
-0.6, -0.19, -0.41, 0.11, -0.46, -3.08, -2.09, 1.27, -1.5, 0.57, 
-1.69, 0.86, -0.12, -0.22, -0.85, 0.66, 0.11, -1.15, 0.32, -0.36, 
-0.42, -1.17, -0.71, 0.45, -0.41, 0.43, 2.18, 0.39, 0.1, -0.12, 
1.64, -1.24, -1.14, 1.22), vint1 = c(7L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 
8L, 10L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 
9L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 
3L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 4L), vfac1 = structure(c(2L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("vnum1", 
"vint1", "vfac1"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")


> head(ddf)
  vnum1 vint1 vfac1
1 -1.38     7     2
2  1.22     7     4
3 -0.17     9     2
4 -0.47     6     1
5 -0.08     6     1
6 -1.11     2     2
>
```

I want to create a matrix which will have unique values of vint1 as rows, unique values of vfac1 as columns. The matrix needs to be filled with mean values of vnum1 for corresponding vint1 and vfac1. I tried following function:

```
df2mat = function(gdf){
        for(i in sort(unique(vint1))) cat("\t",i)
        cat("\n")
        for(j in sort(levels(vfac1))) {
                cat("j:",j)
                sum =0
                for(j in 1:10){
                        cat(with(gdf[vint1==i & vfac1==j,], mean(vnum1, na.rm=T)),"\t")
                        #cat("\t")
                        }
                cat("\n")
        }
        cat("\n")
}   

> df2mat(ddf)
         1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
j: 1-0.6033333  NaN     -0.51   0.25    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN 
j: 2-0.6033333  NaN     -0.51   0.25    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN 
j: 3-0.6033333  NaN     -0.51   0.25    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN 
j: 4-0.6033333  NaN     -0.51   0.25    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

It produces an output which is not correct since values of first row are being repeated. Moreover, missing values are producing NaN error. Also how can I get this into a proper matrix object? How can I correct these problems. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your code uses several bad idioms: 1) Explicit `for` loops; 2) using `cat` (which prints the values) instead of collecting result in a matrix object. I highly recommend learning proper R idioms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be a good use of the standard `tapply` with two factors. You can do

```
with(ddf, tapply(vnum1, list(vint1,vfac1), mean))

#            1       2          3      4
#1  -0.8500000 -1.6900         NA     NA
#2          NA -0.6650 -0.6000000     NA
#3  -0.4100000  0.6150 -2.0900000 -0.050
#4  -0.4600000      NA  0.1075000  0.825
#5   0.1000000  0.8000  2.1800000     NA
#6  -0.2750000  0.8600  0.6600000  0.390
#7  -0.1300000 -0.1775         NA  1.220
#8          NA -0.4300 -0.7266667     NA
#9  -0.1200000 -1.1900 -0.1900000     NA
#10 -0.6033333      NA -0.5100000  0.250
```

Comment: Excellent. Base R really does have a lot of under-appreciated functions.

Comment: This is truly good. An inspiration for me to learn *apply functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `acast` from `reshape2` package, which gives you what you need:

```
library(reshape2)
acast(ddf, vint1 ~ vfac1, fun.aggregate = mean, value.var = 'vnum1')

             1       2          3      4
1  -0.8500000 -1.6900        NaN    NaN
2         NaN -0.6650 -0.6000000    NaN
3  -0.4100000  0.6150 -2.0900000 -0.050
4  -0.4600000     NaN  0.1075000  0.825
5   0.1000000  0.8000  2.1800000    NaN
6  -0.2750000  0.8600  0.6600000  0.390
7  -0.1300000 -0.1775        NaN  1.220
8         NaN -0.4300 -0.7266667    NaN
9  -0.1200000 -1.1900 -0.1900000    NaN
10 -0.6033333     NaN -0.5100000  0.250
```

Comment: This also works well. But 'tapply' answer above is clealy simpler and more easy to use. Moreover, it give NA rather than NaN values in case of missing data. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. `tapply` is important, both conceptually and in applications. There is also a bunch of libraries - `reshape2`, `data.table`, `dplyr2`, `ggplot2` that extend R in important ways and I recommend to learn them all.

Comment: It's quite easy to convert `NaN` above to `NA` - if `m` is the matrix with the answer, `m[is.nan(m)] <- NA` will do the conversion.